# Expo / React Native storage limitations

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I'm looking at file storage options using Expo and it seems that Async Storage is the only supported option. However it is documented that there is a 6MB limit on Android for this. I'm curious, how do native apps like Netflix/Spotify (for example) utilise hundreds of MB's of storage space? Is this not possible with Expo / React Native? I need to store around 50mb of JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

look at this
[Expo File System](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/)

(saving files in this way is not so secure and maybe can be read by user. but you can save large files with it)